# Original Android Emulator with Hyper-V

Tags: android, android-emulator, hyper-v

I've tried the new Hyper-V support for the Android Emulator which was released yesterday (see here [release-post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/android-emulator-amd-processor-hyper-v.html)) but I didn't get it to work. I always get the following error message

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
```

Does someone get it without HAXM and Hyper-V support to work?

EDIT:
I meet all the requisitions:

- Android Studio 3.2 Beta 2
- Android Emulator 27.3.8
- Intel i5-4690 with support for VT-x, UG and EPT
- Activated Hyper-V

Basically it should work.

Comment: you need hardware acceleration to use it, this is off topic

Comment: Yes. Vtx is enabled and Hyper-V installed. Also the right android studio (3.2 beta2) and emulator 27.3.8 is installed. So it should work.

Comment: I am running into the same thing. All the requirements are met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meh. Classic rtfm problem. You have to activate the "Hyper Visor Platform" not only the "Hyper-V Platform". It's a little bit misleading because the names are pretty equal.

Nontheless after activating the right feature it will work.